# Printing a number in the stack with NASM Assembly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, nasm, 32-bit

Learning NASM Assembly for 32-bit Ubuntu.

Doing a function that simply prints the number you pushed into the stack before calling it:

```
SECTION .text
global main
main:
; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Main
; -----------------------------------------------------------
push    5
call    print_number

; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Exit
; -----------------------------------------------------------
mov EAX,1
int 0x80

; -----------------------------------------------------------
; Prints a number
; -----------------------------------------------------------
print_number:
push    EBP
mov     EBP,ESP

mov     EAX,4
mov     EBX,0
mov     ECX,[EBP + 8]
add     byte [ECX],'0'
mov     EDX,1
int     0x80

pop     EBP
ret
```

Keeps giving me a segmentation fault error.

Let's see... when I call the function, the stack should look like this:

- 5
- Return address

Then I push `EBP`:

- 5
- Return address
- EBP

I want `EBP` to contain the address of the stack's base, so I do this:

```
mov EBP, ESP
```

So basically `EBP` is now an address to the stack's base. Since `ECX` needs to be the address of whatever I'm going to print, `ECX` should be `EBP` (the address of the stack's base) moved by 8 bytes so that it points to the `5` I want to print:

```
mov ECX,[EBP + 8]
```

And to print it I convert it to ASCII first:

```
add byte [ECX],'0'
```

I can't see the problem here. Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: +1 First well-written question I've seen all day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov ECX,[EPB+8]` moves the value at location `EPB+8` to `ECX`, which is not a valid address. It's just `5`. You could just do:

```
mov   ECX,EPB
add   ECX,8
```